# how to pass data from listview to a method on map activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, listview

I have list of destinations and i want to make a marker on my google map (fragment)  on the position of the destination chosen from the list

for that reason :

toTestLstViewActivity class contains my map fragment and the method gotoDest(LatLng destPosition,String name) that i want to call when an item on my list view is clicked
i tried to  use intent but doesn't work

### toTestLstViewActivity.java

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class toTestLstViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoints;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker , mCurrLocationMarkerInit;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    String namedest,latdest,lngdest;
    LatLng positionDest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_test_lst_view);



        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment3);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        namedest = getIntent().getStringExtra(PoleFragment.Name_EXTRA);
        latdest = getIntent().getStringExtra(PoleFragment.Name_EXTRA);
        lngdest = getIntent().getStringExtra(PoleFragment.Name_EXTRA);
        positionDest= new LatLng( Double.parseDouble(latdest),Double.parseDouble(lngdest));
        gotoDest(positionDest,namedest);

    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(33.795964, 2.849461))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
                .title("city A")
                .snippet("city A"));
        goToLocationZoom(33.795964, 2.849461,11);


    }
    public void goToLocationZoom(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

    public void gotoDest(LatLng destPosition,String name) {

        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(destPosition.latitude, destPosition.longitude))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
                .title(name)
                .snippet(name));
        goToLocationZoom(destPosition.latitude, destPosition.longitude,14);

    }


}
```

### PoleFragment.java Contains my list view

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.ami.fundapter.BindDictionary;
    import com.ami.fundapter.FunDapter;
    import com.ami.fundapter.extractors.StringExtractor;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.util.ArrayList;


    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     * Use the {@link PoleFragment#newInstance} factory method to
     * create an instance of this fragment.
     */
    public class PoleFragment extends Fragment {
        // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
        private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
        private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

        public toTestLstViewActivity myMap = new toTestLstViewActivity();
        public static String Name_EXTRA ;
        public static String  Lat_EXTRA;
        public static String  Lng_EXTRA;
        // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
        private String mParam1;
        private String mParam2;


        public PoleFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment PoleFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        public static PoleFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
            PoleFragment fragment = new PoleFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
                mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pole, container, false);

            final ArrayList<PolesList> poles= new ArrayList<>() ;

            PolesList p1 = new PolesList("Pole centrale",33.799812, 2.853941 );
            PolesList p2 = new PolesList("Pole Biologie",33.796014, 2.849572);
            PolesList p3 = new PolesList("Pole gestion",33.809007, 2.862432);
            PolesList p4 = new PolesList("Pole khneg",33.7590803,2.7861719);
            poles.add(p1);
            poles.add(p2);
            poles.add(p3);
            poles.add(p4);

            BindDictionary<PolesList> dictionary=new BindDictionary<>();
            dictionary.addStringField(R.id.textPoleName, new StringExtractor<PolesList>() {
                @Override
                public String getStringValue(PolesList pole1, int position) {
                    return pole1.getPoleName();

                }
            });


            FunDapter dapter = new FunDapter(PoleFragment.this.getActivity(),poles,R.layout.pole_layout,dictionary);
            ListView listView= view.findViewById(R.id.polelist);
            listView.setAdapter(dapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    PolesList selectedItem= poles.get(position);
Toast.makeText(PoleFragment.this.getActivity(),selectedItem.getPoleName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),toTestLstViewActivity.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra(Name_EXTRA,selectedItem.getPoleName());
                    myIntent.putExtra(Lat_EXTRA,selectedItem.getLat());
                    myIntent.putExtra(Lng_EXTRA,selectedItem.getLng());

                    startActivityForResult(myIntent,2);

                }
            });

            return view;
        }

    }
```

*Thanks For Your Help !*

Comment: use interface to do that your list fragment is also in the map activity ryt ??

Comment: example ?? please

Comment: i have updated the code ask if there are any problem 1st create a java class interface the use its method to pass the value ...and interfaces method will call your activity function goToDest..